# Authorize.net - company field?

Tags: authorize.net

I am trying to show company field in aNet form. Added

```
  "company"  => "123LTD",
```

as one of options to the

....["transactionRequest"]["billTo"]

Settings. Even made this field required. With no luck.
How to show it?